# Delete scheduled taskname containing space

Tags: command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks, findstr

I want to delete scheduled tasks that start with "Adobe Acrobat" eg "Adobe Acrobat 123","Adobe Acrobat 456","Adobe Acrobat 789"

```
schtasks /Delete /TN Adobe* /F
```

This command fails to find any tasks cos its literally searching for the taskname "Adobe*"

```
for /f %%x in ('schtasks /query ^| findstr Adobe') do schtasks /Delete /TN %%x /F
```

This works only for tasknames without space, eg only finds taskname if its "AdobeAcorbat123"

How can I delete all scheduled tasksnames starting with "Adobe" and containing space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo list ^| findstr /r "TaskName.*Adobe"') do schtasks /delete /tn "%%b" /f
```

The *findstr* portion uses regex (regular expressions) to extract only the lines containing the strings "TaskName" and "Adobe" from the output of *schtasks*. This is then tokenised by `for /f` (see `for /?` for more) and the second token containing the full path to the task (*including spaces*) is extracted and passed to another *schtasks* command that deletes said task.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Added some more details.

Comment: @Karan Thanks! Didnt think about using the list format. =)